# Joi: how to validate only one of two keys (with array)?

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

Let's say I have `user` object with `id` number and `roles` array:

```js
const user = {
  id: 1,
  roles: [ 'admin' ]
};
```

And validation of this object should pass if:

1. `id` is matching some external value
2. OR `roles` includes `admin` string

I've tried this approach but it doesn't work as expected:

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  id: Joi.number().valid(Joi.ref('$userId')), // shouldn't pass as $userId === 2
  roles: Joi.array().has(Joi.string().valid('admin')) // should pass as user has 'admin' role
}).or('id');

schema.validate(user, {
  context: {
    userId: 2
  }
}); // should pass as `user` includes `admin` in `roles` (but `userId` not equals `user.id`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, this scenario can be accomplished using `when` operation:

```js
Joi.object({
  id: Joi.number(),
  roles: Joi.array().when('id', { 
    not: Joi.ref('$userId'), 
    then: Joi.array().has(Joi.string().valid('admin'))
  })
});
```